# Can I create an object of an Activity in other class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have defined a function in `MainActivity` now I want to access the function from another class in my app. I have created an object of the `MainActivity` and with that object I have called the function. Although there is no error, it's not executing. Every time I try to execute, the app crashes.

Comment: u just pass the context of activity class....

Comment: you need to pass the context you can use getApplicationContext()

Comment: try the below link and hope use full to you:-

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240413/how-to-pass-android-application-context-to-a-java-class>

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734791/how-to-pass-context-from-activity-to-activity>

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Activity A should have a variable

```
static ActivityA activityA;
```

In onCreate state:

```
activityA = this;
```

and add this method:

```
public static ActivityA getInstance(){
   return   activityA;
 }
```

In activity B, call

```
ActivityA.getInstance().myFunction(); //call myFunction using activityA
```

Comment: +1 for answer...This is what I have discussed with Raghav Sood the answer belwo his comments

Comment: Yes, this is only needed if a top activity should control the activity below it. e.g. one can use a transparent activity as a graphic interface to control an activity below it. Otherwise it is better that the function is a static one in a separate utilities class and pass the context if required.

Comment: its called methods but can't change setbackgroundresources().... of  imageView ....

Comment: Didn't get the `myFunction`

Comment: Thank you so much it is working fine.
Creating any activity's object using the code 
`MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();` will not go through any life cycle of activity and will generate null pointer exception.

Comment: @Lumis Will this not lead to memory leak? If Android decides to destroy activity under memory pressure, you are holding reference to Activity which is destroyed !!!

Comment: This will cause memory leak, instead you could create an interface and implement inside your activity

Comment: Using this approach how will you give the guarantee that the static activity object gets garbage collected when the system needs it to.

Comment: This could cause memory leaks. right?

Answer (score 19):

You cannot just create objects of Activities by using:

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity();
```

as you would with normal Java classes. All Activities in Android must go through the Activity lifecycle so that they have a valid context attached to them.

By treating an Activity as a normal Java class, you end up with a null context. As most methods in an Activity are called on its Context, you will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

Instead, move all such methods which need to be called from other classes into a Utility class which accepts a valid context in its constructor, and then use that context in the methods to do the work.

Comment: I know about using generic util class for the accessing the common methods...But What about taking a static method in the activity and calling it by using the class name...? Is it wrong? what Happens if we do like so..

Comment: @Pragnani Static methods cannot refer to non static members of a class. As the class context is not static, you will still get an error.

Comment: ,yeah I know that..but How can we access the static method of Calender class i.e Calender.getInstance() in the our non static class..eventhough it is factory method but it is static

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() is used to return an Instance of the calendar class based on your locale etc, which you use to call other methods on the calendar class.

Comment: Sorry I know the usage of the Calender.getInstance() method, in the previous comment You've said that we can't use static methods in the non static members of a class, but You missed something that "If can not refer static members in the not static content" but we can use the static method in our class

Comment: that's why I have mention getInstance() method, getInstance() method is a static, How do we use it in our class to get the calander instance..What about Thread.CurrentThread()

Comment: You can call static methods from a non static method, but you cannot use a non static variable or method inside a static method.

Comment: @Pragnani Yes. But you cannot make a static method in your Activity that calls anything using the Activity instance or context and then call it in another class

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable public and then create object in adapter like this:

```
public int i;  // Variable in Activity class

((ActivityName) context).i          // accessing in adapter
```