# How to call a method in MainActivity from another class?

Tags: java, android

How do I call the method `startChronometer` in another class when the method is declared inside the main activity?

Inside `MainActivity`:

```
public void startChronometer() {
    mChronometer.start();
    showElapsedTime();
}
```

Inside another class, I tried to do this:

```
MainActivity mActivity;
mActivity.startChronometer();
```

But an error occurred which said:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException.
```

May I know what more I need to add to the code?

Comment: `MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
mActivity.startChronometer();`

Comment: But are you sure you are not calling non-activity functions?

Comment: I did MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity(); mActivity.startChronometer(); but it doesn't work too. @PankajKumar

Comment: May I know how can I improve on it? What is a better way of achieving the same result? @STTLCU

Comment: thats the reason I was asking about if you are doing some non-activity task or not. here again you will get NPE for `mChronometer`. So you should think about it

Comment: Yes it's a non-activity task. How can I call a non-activity task then? @PankajKumar

Comment: You should have activity classes only for activity related purposes. Please define standard classes for any non-activity purposes, like chronometers. Then use those classes inside your activity as much as you need @shannon

Comment: @PankajKumar FWIW, it's almost never a good idea to use `new` with activity classes, including this case. (Yeah, old post, got active today by someone posting a new answer.)

Comment: @laalto Yes you are correct. Same reason I was trying to make sure into my second comment. Sometime it happens, many developer wrote normal class and write name with activity postfix. Thank you for your valuable comment :)

Comment: Hi @shannon! My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260557/3767765 seems to be helping a lot of people even though it isn't the accepted answer. Can you accept it, please?

Answer (score 43):

You can easily call a method from any Fragment inside your Activity by doing a cast like this:

**Java**

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).startChronometer();
```

**Kotlin**

```
(activity as MainActivity).startChronometer()
```

Just remember to make sure this Fragment's activity is in fact MainActivity before you do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Not from FRAGMENT, but from another ACTIVITY class.

Comment: I see your point but you should never call an Activity from another Activity class @ekashking, it would lead to memory leaks if you do it. At most you can have an observer pattern to update an Activity that's not on screen.

Answer (score 31):

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void myMethod() {
       // do something...
    }
)
```

***AnotherClass.java***

```
public Class AnotherClass() {
     // call this method
     MainActivity.getInstance().myMethod();
}
```

Comment: This caused memory leak!!

Comment: @DeboraCarnevali how to fix it?

Answer (score 15):

What I have done with no memory leaks or lint warnings is to use @f.trajkovski's method, but instead of using `MainActivity`, use `WeakReference<MainActivity>` instead.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static WeakReference<MainActivity> weakActivity;
// etc..
 public static MainActivity getmInstanceActivity() {
    return weakActivity.get();
}
}
```

Then in MainActivity OnCreate()

```
weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(MainActivity.this);
```

Then in another class

```
MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().yourMethod();
```

Works like a charm

Comment: That's interesting. No more memory leak warning. Hmm...

Answer (score 4):

Initialize it first

```
MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
```

Then you can continue

```
mActivity.startChronometer();
```

Comment: instead-of giving the same new answer you can upvote the existing one. Right?

Comment: FWIW, never instantiate activity classes with `new`.

Comment: @laalto I never did android. This is just a hint to initialize `mActivity` to avid `NPE`. You can initialize it appropriately.

Comment: @PankajKumar I am sorry who provide answer first?

Comment: There are literally tens of android questions posted every day where the root problem is instantiating an activity with `new`. Such activities are not good for anything as they are not really initialized. Therefore suggestions to use `new` in this context are bad.

Comment: @laalto ahh really.. I haven't look in to them.

Comment: @laalto You should put your idea right under comment section in the question since there is a comment what exactly say to initialize using `new`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in sub Fragment of `MainActivity` to call the method on it.

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).startChronometer();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass instance of MainActivity into another class, then you can call everything public (in MainActivity) from everywhere.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Instance of AnotherClass for future use
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create new instance of AnotherClass and
        // pass instance of MainActivity by "this"
        anotherClass = new AnotherClass(this);
    }

    // Method you want to call from another class
    public void startChronometer(){
        ...
    }
}
```

**AnotherClass.java**

```
public class AnotherClass {

    // Main class instance
    private MainActivity mainActivity;  

    // Constructor
    public AnotherClass(MainActivity activity) {

        // Save instance of main class for future use
        mainActivity = activity;  

        // Call method in MainActivity
        mainActivity.startChronometer();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call methods or fields from  `Activity` in another class like this: `((MainActivity)context)startChronometer();` but how do you plain to triger that method in your custom class?

Comment: Sorry, iam not sure if i fully understand your question. You are saying, that i can call method of MainActivity by its context, but still, you need to pass that context just like MainActivity instance reference by "this" when calling constructor of AnotherClass. So i assume, its same approach. Then there is question how do i plan to trigger (call) that method (startChronometer?) in my solution (in AnotherClass). So my answer is, i will call that method by mainActivity.startChronometer();

Do I understand it correctly? Thank you for yours post :)

Comment: I mean how do you gonna call `((MainActivity)context)startChronometer();` in your `AnotherClass`?

Comment: Same way like you. You are just retyping context to MainActivity, iam using MainActivity from start, so i dont need to retype like you.

mainActivity.startChronometer();

Answer (score 2):

What i have done and it works is create an instance in the MainActivity and getter for that instance:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AbstractMainActivity {
    private static MainActivity mInstanceActivity;
    public static MainActivity getmInstanceActivity() {
    return mInstanceActivity;
    }
```

And the in the onCreate method just point to that activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mInstanceActivity = this;
}
```

And in onDestroy you should set this instance to null:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mInstanceActivity = null;
}
```

Later you can call every method in whatever class you want:

```
MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().yourMethod();
```

Comment: This will cause memory leaks and break instant run

Comment: I have used this on three applications which are in production now and there is no memory leaks or break instant run. You are creating a reference to point to a object how can this cause memory leak? Have you tested it ?

Comment: I have used this in non-activity classes but I was under the impression storing an activity object is bad. You also get a lint error saying this with android studio if you store an activity object.

Comment: I don't get the part: storing an activity object is bad. In this scenario android is creating the object, with this code you are just creating a reference that will point to that object. It doesn't matter where you are using it until the activity is alive. For that reason usually I am checking if the activity is alive or not.

Comment: If its your main activity perhaps it would be okay because it will continue to be used while the app is being used, but its still bad practice. There is quite a lot of material out there explaining why storing static context references is bad, im still getting up to scratch on the subject myself

Comment: Thanks for that information, basically what needs to be added in this scenario is to set this instance to null in onDestroy.

Answer (score 1):

> But an error occurred which says java.lang.NullPointerException.

Thats because, you never initialized your MainActivity. you should initialize your object before you call its methods.

```
MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();//make sure that you pass the appropriate arguments if you have an args constructor
mActivity.startChronometer();
```

Comment: FWIW, never instantiate activity classes with `new`.

Comment: Activities don't have constructors with arguments! If there is one defined, something is done wrong

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, if passing `MainActivity` as a `Context` into a fragment, you can also do:

```kotlin
(context as MainActivity).startChronometer()
```

to cast context to MainActivity and before using it.

Answer (score 0):

i personally would take in the context as an argument when instantiating the OtherClass inside MainActivity, and inside the OtherClass, explicitly cast it into MainActivity type for whenever i need it.

inside MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(this);
}
```

inside OtherClass:

```
public class OtherClass {
   private Context context;

   public OtherClass(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
   }

   public whateverMethod() {
       ((MainActivity) context).startChronometer();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply, You can make this method static as below:

```
public static void startChronometer(){
    mChronometer.start();
    showElapsedTime();
}
```

you can call this function in other class as below:

```
MainActivity.startChronometer();
```

Comment: instead-of giving the same new answer you can upvote the existing one. Right?

Comment: `mChronometer` would then need to be static, and not tied to the instance of the class in which the object exists... Downvote

Answer (score -1):

Easy method

Use "static" keyword just like this

```
public static void startChronometer()
{
  // Your code
}
```

Then call method from your other class like this

```
MainActivity.startChronometer();
```

Hope this work thank you

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -3):

You can make this method static.

```
public static void startChronometer(){
        mChronometer.start();
        showElapsedTime();
    }
```

you can call this function in other class as below:

```
MainActivity.startChronometer();
```

OR

You can make an object of the main class in second class like,

```
MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
mActivity.startChronometer();
```

Comment: instead-of giving the same new answer you can upvote the existing one. Right?

Comment: mChronometer seems to be a private property of a MainActivity istance. This won't work unless mChronometer is static too.

Comment: FWIW, never instantiate activity classes with `new`.