# Android Another Activity call Main Activity Databasehelper Function fail

Tags: java, android

Databasehelp.java

```
package com.example.abc2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "DB_BusData";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
  * Constructor
  * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
  * @param context
  */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}   

/**
  * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
  * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{

//By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
//of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
this.getReadableDatabase();

try {

copyDataBase();

} catch (IOException e) {

throw new Error("Error copying database");

}
}

}

/**
  * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
  * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
  */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
  * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
  * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
  * This is done by transfering bytestream.
  * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

// Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
// You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
// to you to create adapters for your views.

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void printInspectorFormat(){
    try {
        Log.d(null,"1234545");
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        try { 
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
        } catch (IOException ioe) { 
        throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
        }  
        try {  
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
        }catch(SQLException sqle){  
        throw sqle;  
        }
}
```

UltililyActivity.java

```
MainActivity cls2= new MainActivity();
cls2.printInspectorFormat();
```

when in Ultility Activity i m trying to call the Main activity Function, But return error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Maybe databasehelper does not share? or what? how to solve this?

Comment: Never do `new ...Activity()`. It is not going to work. Pass in your own context.

Comment: you should never create an instance of activity class.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Comment: @zapl how to solve this? example? please

Comment: @Raghunandan Same Error..can't work

Comment: @ChinYe i din't provide a solution. only posted a link which tells no to creating an instance of activity class. Have the code of `printInspectorFormat()` in activity class and  `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(ActivtiyName.this);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(ActivtiyName.this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create instances of `Activity` yourself. They lack the `Context` that is added by the system when it creates them. Almost anything you can do with an `Activity` will fail if you created it yourself via `new Activity()`.

But you can move your `printInspectorFormat` into another class responsible for database access and add a `Context` parameter. Now every `Activity` can use the method by passing itself as context.

```
class DbBackend {
    public static void printInspectorFormat(Context context) {
        try {
            Log.d(null,"1234545");
            DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            try { 
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
            } catch (IOException ioe) { 
            throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
            }  
            try {  
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
            }catch(SQLException sqle){  
            throw sqle;  
            }
    }
}
```

from any `Activity`

```
DbBackend.printInspectorFormat(this);
```

You should also consider using a solid implementation for asset based databases like https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper since yours does not look very safe. And maybe read a tutorial like http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html which also shows you some pattern how to use SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: can i give u a kiss? a thousands thanks. it is work !