# calling another class in android (java)

Tags: android

This is my list.java class

```
package com.FoodOrderApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class list extends Activity
{
    private ListView m_listview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        m_listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is my method to call class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    initDishRestaurantView(rootView);
    list l = new list();
}
```

What is the proper way to call/construct list class (to add items to list)?
I know that this question is kinda noob one, but I havent found an answer ;/

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but you should change your class name to be capital `List`. This follows Java conventions. Keep variables and method names lowercase, but capitalize class names.

Comment: You're thinking in totally wrong direction. You should read a book about java and a book about Android first.

Comment: Do you fragment and is it associated with list?

Comment: Looks like I really need to dive into java. Been developing c++/c# for years, but java is kinda different. Yes I do use fragments, its not assosiated tho

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate `Activity` classes like this

```
list l = new list();
```

you start them with an `Intent` and `startActivity`.  You can create a class that doesn't `extends Activity` and have `getters/setters` or whatever methods you need. One could even be called `addToList(Object foo)` which adds to a `List` object.

You will probably want to take a little time and go through **[The Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)**  to understand how to create classes and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
  public class list extends Activity
```

Its a activity class. And you have

```
  list l = new list(); // wrong
```

Check the answer by Raghav Sood

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Use

```
 startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),list.class); 
 // use getActivity() if in fragment or ActivityName.this in activity class
```

You can pass values using intents.

Answer (score 0):

startActivity and putStringExtra to Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, list.class);
String[] myStrings = new String[] {"item1", "item2"};
intent.putExtra("strings", myStrings);
startActivity(intent);
```

then at your list class `list.java`

get argument by use `getStringExtra()`