# Unable to pass a value from one class to another in android

Tags: android, pass-by-value

I am facing an issue: a value is not getting transferred from one class to another.

The value is picked inside a class, but when retrieving it in another class I am getting null.

Below is the class where the value is set.

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{

    String getentry=null;
    Database d=new Database(this);
    StockTable st=new StockTable();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stockmanager);

    final Button AddStock=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final EditText entry=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button BroDetail=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        AddStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getentry=entry.getText().toString();
                d.db.insert(st.tablename, null,st.insert());


            }
        });
                }
}
```

In this class I am using the value `getentry` but I am getting null.

```
public class StockTable {

final String tablename="StockTable";
private String column1="Stock_ID";
private String column2="StockName";

stockmanager sm=new stockmanager();

final String stocktable = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + 
            " (" + column1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " + column2 + " TEXT) ";

public ContentValues insert(){

    ContentValues cvi=new ContentValues();
    for(int i=0;i<=sm.getentry.length();i++)
    {
        cvi.put(column1, 1);
        cvi.put(column2,sm.getentry);
                    }

    return cvi;
}

public void delete(){


}
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: where is db initialized?

Comment: I have only pasted half code I mean only that code that is giving me the problem. It is initialized in another class but the issue here is getentry is null in stock table class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
public class stockmanager extends Activity{
```

And you are instantiating a activity class

`stockmanager sm=new stockmanager()`.

You should not instantiate a activity class. It is wrong. Instead you can pass the value to the method itself or to the constructor of other class.

You can do as

```
StockTable st=new StockTable();
st.insert(your params);
```

Then in StockTable have a insert method that takes params

```
public ContentValues insert(params){
```

Comment: oh thanks raghunandan for your reply.. so can you give idea what is best approach to do this as I need `getentry` in stock table class.

Comment: ok its better that we pass as params to method..thanks let me try that way

Comment: @Siva what is the problem in doing that?

Comment: Actually I am new to both java and android learning both.. when I am doing in the explained I am getting null in `getentry` variable.

Comment: @Siva Follow the suggestion and try forget the rest

Comment: Here one problem I can't pass params to `insert` because insert already has some params so I can't pass any new params... Is there anyway out for this

Comment: @Siva i don't see insert method taking params in stocktable.

Comment: @Raghunandan.. can you please once confirm that we shouldn't create objects to activity class. right? I am new to android so asking somany questions

Comment: @Siva absolutely sure that instatiating activity class is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do. But constructor `new stockmanager()` in StockTable will not fire `onCreate()` method.

You need to pass your `Activity` to StockTable class like:

```
public StockTable(stockmanager yourActivity)
{
 this.st = yourActivity;
}
```

Comment: how to pass a activity.. I am new to android

Comment: Already i show the example of constructor.
just use this constructor like : `StockTable st=new StockTable(this);`