# Calling Method from other Java Class

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My slot machine is still in progress. I am trying to get a method from one class to another but I can't figure it out. Could anyone please help me? Here is my first code which I wanted to call the method from the other class:

GameMainActivity:

```
package com.ics136leeward.slotmachine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class GameMainActivity extends Activity {
ViewFlipper slotOne, slotTwo, slotThree, spinStop;
Button spin, stop, bet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);
    this.initSpin();
    this.initStop();
}

private void initSpin() { //initialize Spin Method
    spin = (Button) findViewById (R.id.spinBtn);
    slotOne = (ViewFlipper) findViewById (R.id.slot1);
    slotTwo = (ViewFlipper) findViewById (R.id.slot2);
    slotThree = (ViewFlipper) findViewById (R.id.slot3);
    spinStop = (ViewFlipper) findViewById (R.id.spinstopbutton);
    spin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slotOne.setFlipInterval(40); 
            slotOne.startFlipping(); //slot 1 spin
            slotTwo.setFlipInterval(50); 
            slotTwo.startFlipping(); //slot 2 spin
            slotThree.setFlipInterval(60); 
            slotThree.startFlipping(); //slot 3 spin
            spinStop.showNext(); // shows the stop button

        }
    });

} 

private void initStop() { //initialize Stop Method
    stop = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stopBtn);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            slotOne.stopFlipping(); //stops slot 1
            slotTwo.stopFlipping(); //stops slot 2
            slotThree.stopFlipping(); //stops slot 3
            spinStop.showNext(); //shows the spin button again

            if(slotOne == slotTwo || slotTwo == slotThree) {

            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is the second java class which I wanted to call the method getBet1() and getBet5() to the first activity:

Bet:

```
package com.ics136leeward.slotmachine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bet extends Activity {
TextView userBet, bankRoll, event;
final int BETONE = 1, BETFIVE = 5;
int uBet = 100, bet;

public void getBet1() {
    userBet = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.userBet);
    bankRoll = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.bankroll);
    uBet -= BETONE;
    bet += BETONE;
    userBet.setText("Your Bet: " + bet);
    bankRoll.setText("" + uBet);

    return;
}

public void getBet5() {
    userBet = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.userBet);
    bankRoll = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.bankroll);
    uBet -= BETFIVE;
    bet += BETFIVE;
    userBet.setText("Your Bet: " + bet);
    bankRoll.setText("" + uBet);

    return;
}
}
```

Comment: `Bet myBet = new Bet()` ... `myBet.getBet1()`? Just noticed this is `android`. Not sure how that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a Utility class not a Activity class

So change

```
public class Bet extends Activity {
```

to

```
public class Bet  // Normal java class
```

Since its not a Activity class there is not need to initialize views

```
userBet = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.userBet); //remove them
// Initialize all yours views in Activity
```

Now in Activity class

```
Bet bet = new Bet();
int value =bet.getBet1();
```

In `getBet1()` do you calculations an return values.

Then in `Activity` you can set the value to `TextView`

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Do also check raghav's answer @

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Answer (score 0):

you can define those method `static` and then call by its `class name` like

```
Bet.getBet1();
Bet.getBet5();
```

or simply you can create class `object` and then call it

```
Bet b = new Bet();
b.getBet1()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: You don't need to extend to Activity class as you are not using any UI. (Already suggested by Raghunandan)

Try this code in the `onCreate` method  of your calling class i.e. `GameMainActivity`

```
    Bet bet= new Bet(); // where bet is object of Bet Class
    bet.getBet1();
    bet.getBet5();
```

However, You can create the object of `Bet` class in any method and access the class methods provided their access modifier must be `public`.

Comment: But `Bet` is a Activity class and creating an instance of Activity class is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Comment: @Raghunandan As you have already suggested not to extend Activity. I have posted this in reference to that only.