# Application not Starting

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I am new to android programming and recently started making a practice application.

Although the code is error free the app when launched in the emulator says "Unfortunately PocketMoney has stopped"

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate  activity  
ComponentInfo{com.example.pocketmoney/com.example.pocketmoney.PocketMoney}:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class PocketMoney extends Activity {


final String TAG="pocketmoney";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i(TAG, "Now in onCreate() ");
    final Button NonMeal_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nonmeal_button);
    final Button Meal_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.meal_button);
    if(checkPocketValues()==false)
    {
        startSettings_Activity();
    }
    Meal_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //listener for Meal_Button 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startMeal_Money_Activity();
        }
    });
    NonMeal_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //Listener for NonMeal_button 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startNonMeal_Money_Activity();  
        }
    });

}
void startSettings_Activity(){
//to start Settings_Activity
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings_Activity.class));
}
void startMeal_Money_Activity()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Meal_Money_Activity.class));
}
void startNonMeal_Money_Activity()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(this,NonMeal_Money_Activity.class));
}


boolean checkPocketValues()
{
    //to check if Pocket values are filled

    boolean SettingsFilled=true;
    Settings_Activity check=new Settings_Activity();
    if((check.preferences.getFloat(check.MealMoney,0)==0)&&check.preferences.getFloat(check.NonMealMoney, 0)==0)
    {
        SettingsFilled=false;

    }

        return SettingsFilled;
}
public void onStop()
{
    Log.i(TAG,"now onStop method is called ");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pocket_money, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: post your logcat error code and manifest file code

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException`, possibly in your `onCreate` method. Post the full stack trace and comment the line where the number is specified in the stack trace.

Comment: please show `main.xml` layout

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Settings_Activity check=new Settings_Activity(); // wrong
```

Looks like `Settings_Activity` is a Activity class and you are instantiating the same which is wrong

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Quoting Raghav

> By treating an Activity as a normal Java class, you end up with a null
>   context. As most methods in an Activity are called on its Context, you
>   will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

And you do have this

```
(check.preferences.getFloat(check.MealMoney,0)
```

So the crash is probably bcoz of this `Settings_Activity check=new Settings_Activity();`

Answer (score 1):

```
void startSettings_Activity(){
//to start Settings_Activity
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings_Activity.class));
}
```

replace it by :

```
 void startSettings_Activity(){
//to start Settings_Activity
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Settings_Activity.class));
}
```

Comment: this has nothing to with the crash