# Accessing another activity's layout Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Well my question may be a bit immature but I'm really wandering about it. 
How can I access the layout of activity A from the class of activity B. i.e I want to change the image in `xml` file of Activity A from activity B.
Is it possible? Kindly help.

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901586/how-to-open-xml-layouts-from-another-activity-layout-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it in such a way. I suggest you to look at the [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Start `Activity B`, do all the needed work there and once you are done, you'll be returned to the `Activity A` and considering the data you get at the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), you can change the image at the content view of `Activity A`

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. I didn't know about startACtivityForResult..Hopefully it will solve my problem now.Thankss :) @nikis

Answer (score 0):

No you can't access views of one Activity in another. You can Navigate to another Activity and change the image there.

You set a layout for each Activity and Each Activity has a life cycle.

Comment: Seems like it is a comment not an answer

Comment: @Sukan how is that so? and if you think so flag it accordignly

Comment: Thankyou but how can I do that without opening that activity..i.e can I use intent and putexrtra to just change the image in other class without launching it? any example plz?

Comment: @NaumanAslam you can't. You need to navigate to Activity B and then change the image there. At a time only one Activity is displayed on the screen.

Comment: @NaumanAslam : **"...change the image in other class without launching it?"** Your use of the words "other class" describes your problem exactly. An Android `Activity` is not just a "class" it is a special case "class" designed to be a UI framework - if it's not visible or has never been launched then it has no purpose. Further to this, if Activity A starts Activity B then you have no guarantee that Activity A will still be alive when Activity B is visible - the OS might destroy Activity A if system resources are low - unlikely but possible.

Comment: @NaumanAslam and do read the answer by Raghav Sood http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class. Activity class is not a normal java class. this will help in future although directly not related to your issue.

Comment: @Raghunandan I m getting the concept behind this now and though for the time startActivityForResult() was required but  it'll definitly help me in future development.Thanks alot for the help

Comment: @NaumanAslam even in that case you navigate to the appropriate activity but you cannot access view of activity b in activity a

Answer (score 0):

You Can't modify A's Image at a running time becasuse A will be in pause mode when B is in front. You need to `startActivityForResult();(A ----> B);` And in `ActivityForResult()` method you need to right your Handler logic  to change the Image.

In B activity finished you need to set the Result.