# passing arrays another class and asynctask

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i have a problem with AsyncTask and strings arrays... 
I have a splashscreen

SplashScreen.java:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private boolean mIsBackButtonPressed;
private static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 6000; //6 seconds
private Handler myhandler;

int thread;
public String[] lista = new String[200];
public String[] Compagnia = new String[200];
public String[] CodiceVolo = new String[200];
public String[] Citta = new String[200];
public String[] OraPrevista = new String[200];
public String[] OraStimata = new String[200];
public String[] StatoVolo = new String[200];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    new MyTask().execute("");

    myhandler = new Handler();

    // run a thread to start the home screen
    myhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
           finish();

           if (!mIsBackButtonPressed)
           {
                // start the home activity 
            //    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
              //  SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
           }

        }

    }, SPLASH_DURATION); 
}


//handle back button press
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    mIsBackButtonPressed = true;
    super.onBackPressed();
}



public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog prog;
    String info;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreen.this);
        prog.setMessage("Connessione in corso...");
        prog.show();
        prog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        prog.setCancelable(false);
        thread = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {           
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://s.eu").timeout(7*1000).get();

            org.jsoup.nodes.Element tabella = doc.getElementsByClass("tabella-voli").first();
            Iterator<org.jsoup.nodes.Element> iterator = tabella.select("td").iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                thread++;

                Compagnia[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                CodiceVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                Citta[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                OraPrevista[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                OraStimata[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                StatoVolo[thread] = iterator.next().text();
                System.out.println("SPLASH: "+CodiceVolo[thread]);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        prog.dismiss();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
        arrivi fragobj = new arrivi();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
       // intent.putExtra("key",CodiceVolo[2]);

        SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);


       // CheckRow();
    }
}// FINE THREAD
```

I want to print my array in another class.
in arrivi.java:

```
        public class arrivi extends Fragment {

ListView list;
List<RowItem> rowItems;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View arrivi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrivi, container, false); 
   String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
   System.out.println("CODCICE VOLO: "+strtext);


   return arrivi;
}
```

This doesn't work for me...
Crash my app...
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SplashScreen is a Activity class. And doing this `SplashScreen x = new SplashScreen();` is wrong.

Quoting Raghav Sood @

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

> By treating an Activity as a normal Java class, you end up with a null
>   context. As most methods in an Activity are called on its Context, you
>   will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

Instead you can pass the value from `SplashScreen` to `MainActivity` using `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",CodiceVolo[2])
SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Edit:

```
arrivi fragobj = new arrivi();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
fragobj.setArguments(bundle)
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragobj);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: if i want  passing arrays in a fragment?

Comment: passint arrays in fragment??. Elaborate. You can still use intent in fragment

Comment: i can pass the array directly to fragment and start the mainactivity or do I have to pass before mainactivity?

Comment: @roxdragon i don't understand what you want. You can use intent in fragment to start a activity. What do you mean  by "do I have to pass before mainactivity". i have no clue about that

Comment: I have a splashscreen where run an asynctask.
- populate the arrays and i want pass all arrays into the class: public class arrivi extends Fragment {

Comment: @roxdragon check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android. Pls make it clear in your question. You haven't mentioned fragment at all

Comment: yes sorry...in splashscreen.java Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
            arrivi fragobj = new arrivi();
            fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
AND in arrivi class:String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
    System.out.println("CODCICE VOLO: "+strtext); but this crash

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51033/discussion-between-roxdragon-and-raghunandan)

Comment: The link and the code posted works.  Off  to sleep. Post the updated code will update tomo

Comment: i have edited 1st post... in function onPostExecute() can you help me please?

Comment: I  have tried     String strtext = this.getArguments().getString("edttext");
with .this... NullPointer

Comment: I have edited splashscreen.xml and i have edit with <LinearLayout.........    android:background="@drawable/splash">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.gianni.myapp.arrivi" />
</LinearLayout> and in the splashscreen.java:             transaction.replace(R.id.frag, fragobj);
but i get an error : The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, arrivi)