# when call *startActivity* my program not run

Tags: java, android

in my project i use listview (list of program installed in device) and inside listview i have button for each row. when user clicked button i want to delete program. now in arrayadapter (custom list) i have (button.setOnClickListener) when user clicked button my unintall code must run pls help me

my uninstallApp class:

```
 public class UninstallApp extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        public BlackListAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> appsName,
        ArrayList<String> appsPackageName,ArrayList<Drawable> appsIcon) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, appsName);
```

...
.
.
.
}

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                   btnDell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

        Uri packageUri =Uri.parse("package:com.mk88.rootdetection");

            Intent uninstallIntent =
                 new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
                  //  where runing startactivity ?????
            //startActivity(uninstallIntent);

        }
    });

    return rowView;
}


 } 
}
```

but when clicked button my program has stop. pls help me. tnx

Comment: Maybe you'll give us logcat?...

Comment: "UninstallApp uninstallApp = new UninstallApp();"
 Instantiating Activities with NEW is a no-no. Create them using Intents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never instantiate Activity class

You have

```
  UninstallApp uninstallApp = new UninstallApp();
```

and `UninstallApp` is a Activity class.

[Can i Create the object of a activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Activity are declared in manifest and it has a lifecyle.

You can make `UninstallApp` a utility class (normal java class). If you need context you can pass the same to constructor of the class and use the context. `startActivity` is a method of activity class.

Comment: if my uninstallapp code run in mainActivity that is Correct runs but i need another activity to uninstall the app

Comment: @user3555545 then you need to start that activity not by instantiating the same. You never override any of the methods of activity like `onCreate`..

Comment: @user3555545 unless you want another screen you don't require Activity class

Comment: @user3555545 what has that got to do with instantiating activity class??

Comment: in my project i use listview of program installed in device and inside listview i have button for each row. when user clicked button i want to delete program. now in arrayadapter  (custom list) i have button.setOnClickListener when user clicked button my unintall code must run pls help me

Comment: then why do you need a activity class. Make it a normal java class and pass info needed to the construtor of that.

Comment: how?! startactivity need activity class

Comment: @user3555545 can't you pass the context to the constructor of the uninstallapp class. Then use the same to startActivity

Comment: @user3555545 glad the post helped

Comment: i use this post in new project with 2 class. MainActivity And Uninsallapp. in mainactivity,call uninstall function, in uninstall function , call MainActivity.getInstance().dell() and this is ok and run.

Comment: @user3555545 a crash. post the stacktrace or ask a different question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need of another activity to uninstall the app.Also you should not instantiate Activity. Use the below code in your main activity or `Utility` Class

```
 Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" +getPackageName());
 Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);      
 startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i need of another activity to uninstall the app :-(

Comment: @user3555545 no you don't require a Activity class. Never instantiate Activity class

Comment: Calling this intent `Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);      
 startActivity(uninstallIntent);` will take you to another activity.