# NullPointerException while passing a value from a AsyncTask

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
{
    strFullJsonResponse = new LoginService(c).tabsDataService(tabId);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strFullJsonResponse);
        String json = jsonObject.getString("output");
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
        banner = object.getString("bannerurl");
        ELUtil.setPreference(c, "banner", banner);


        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put("bannerurl", banner);
        String bookInfoResponse = object.getString("groupinfo");
        Log.i("EL", "group info is"+bookInfoResponse);
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(bookInfoResponse);
        jsonArrayObject.getString("description"));

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

and this is my setPreference()

```
public static void setPreference(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = ELUtil.getSharedPrefrenceInstance(context);
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value).commit();
}
```

and this is my getSharedPreferenceInstance()

```
public static SharedPreferences getSharedPrefrenceInstance(Context mContext) 
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("le", 0);
    return preferences;
}
```

ELutil is my own class where I am having my own setPreference method and here is my logcat

```
09-08 06:32:10.040: W/System.err(17628): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 06:32:10.210: I/Choreographer(17628): Skipped 289 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-08 06:32:10.260: D/gralloc_goldfish(17628): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-08 06:32:10.290: W/System.err(17628):    at com.tab.tabswipe.ELUtil.getSharedPrefrenceInstance(ELUtil.java:109)
09-08 06:32:10.290: W/System.err(17628):    at com.tab.tabswipe.ELUtil.setPreference(ELUtil.java:159)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at com.tab.async.TabContentAsyncTask.doInBackground(TabContentAsyncTask.java:40)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-08 06:32:10.300: W/System.err(17628):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: POST ur complete code and logcat

Comment: at that point only iam getting exception

Comment: which line is  **TabContentAsyncTask.java:40** ?

Comment: ELUtil.setPreference(c, "banner", banner);

Comment: debug and check **banner** or **c** must be null there

Comment: c is coming null then what i have to do

Comment: what is c there  ? Is it context ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
{
strFullJsonResponse = new LoginService(c).tabsDataService(tabId);
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(strFullJsonResponse);
    String json = jsonObject.getString("output");
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
    banner = object.getString("bannerurl");
    c=getBaseContext();
    ELUtil.setPreference(c, "banner", banner);


    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hashMap.put("bannerurl", banner);
    String bookInfoResponse = object.getString("groupinfo");
    Log.i("EL", "group info is"+bookInfoResponse);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(bookInfoResponse);
    jsonArrayObject.getString("description"));

} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

}
```

## update

1. `getApplicationContext ()` returns the application context of the entire application life cycle,when  application will destroy then it will  destroy also.
2. `this` the context returns the current context of the activity, belong to the activity, the activity is destroyed then it will destroy also.
3. `getBaseContext()` is the method of `ContextWrapper`. And `ContextWrapper` is, "*Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing the original Context.*" (as per javadocs)

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer about how to pass values from an `AsyncTask` to an `Activity`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25262628/3465623