# How to create object of Activity

Tags: android

how to create object of activity and call its life cycle method like a normal java `class`.
for example,

In Android

```
class ABC extends Activity{}
```

---

```
new ABC().onCreate(null);
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: why do you want to create object of an activity? you can start activity using an intent

Comment: Check this link hope its useful. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)

Comment: ActivityThread class in android is responsible for initiating & calling activity's life cycle method depending on related events. Creating an activity object and calling its method like you mentioned will not result your class to behave like a normal activity.

Comment: @BibaswannBandyopadhyay But suppose he is a newbie to Android and he is from the OOPS or java world, what would he assume? Just like anyone else he would assume to access the methods or variable of that class we will have to create an object of that class right, is there something counter intuitive with how the android was designed?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat You got a point. But this is how android works

Comment: @BibaswannBandyopadhyay But android coding is supposedly based on Java (at-least before Kotlin was introduced) & Java is an Object oriented Language, so mine is a very valid point I think.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Yes but android also has it's separate features. Unlike java, android doesn't start execution from main(). Also android has UI components, which are created by android framework and don't require initialization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to start a new activity (like from your main activity to ABC activity), you do it this way

```
Intent i = new intent(this, ABC.class);
startActivity(i);
```

if you looking for passing data, use putExtra() method with the intent.
if your data is much larger, you can always use SharedPreferences or SqlLite database, depending on your need. 
Hope it helps