# Pass data from Activity to Fragment Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There are so many ways but i am using this one:

Activity:(Main2Activity)

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private String myString = "hello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    ...
}

public String getMyData() {
    return myString;
}
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Main2Activity activity = (Main2Activity ) getActivity();
    String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
    return view;
}
}
```

Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   -------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     }
      ---
     private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new MyFragment(), "MyFragment");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

BUT its giving me class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dev03.xyz.Activities.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.MyActivity

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.dev03.xyz.Fragments.Main2Activity
```

-- Package is same.

Thanks

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 3):

You create your Fragment in MainActivity and it belongs to it, so you get MainActivity instead of Main2Activity when you use getAcitvity().

Comment: Yeaaah !!! , this seems to be meaningful .(+1)..And what should i use here in the place of getActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your `getMyData()` static

```
public static String getMyData() {
return myString;
```

}

and then access it in fragment like

```
Main2Activity.getMyData();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity, do the following

```
MyFragment fragmentObj=new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Data_Key", string_value);
fragmentObj.setArguments(args);
```

Now add this Fragment to stack using `FragmentTransaction`.

After this,  in your Fragment class's `onCreateView` do the following

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xml_view, container, false);
  if (getArguments() != null) 
  {
      String valueReceived = getArguments().getString("Data_Key");
  }
 return rootView;
}
```

Comment: It's gud .. but i am following a different way, Not using Transaction or Bundle. I appreciate. Thanks buddy

Comment: @Minkoo This is the standard way. Using getter setter is not advisable.

Comment: Thanks buddy, n you are right , today i read about and even in your it has loose coupling. Thanks i will definitely use this method later.

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of `MainActivity2` and access the method as follow:

```
MainActivity2 mn2=new ManiActivity2();
mn2.getMyData();
```

Comment: You can't create object of Activity.

Comment: Yesssssss !!!  It was a silly mistake but you got that silly one. Thanks Buddy ...

Comment: @Minkoo May be it is working. But creation object of activity is a bad practice for programmers !

Comment: @Piyush ...Nouuu ,I used this, i made object of MainActvity2 and by using this object i got the result  of MainActivity2 in My Fragment class.

Comment: Yeah !! I agree ..even i should use Bundle or Transaction to send data ... My one has method has tight coupling... But You are also right. Thanks Buddy

Comment: @Minkoo Read answer here of Raghav Sood http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to done this work you must have to keep your myFragment into  Main2Activity instead of MainActivity.

Comment: I appreciate , but it was a silly mistake ...  i should use like ,                 MainActivity2 mn2=new ManiActivity2();
mn2.getMyData();

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of MainActivity2 and simply call your getMyData method from Fragment Class

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a whole day , Finally i got the perfect solution: If anyone having the same problem you can follow this answer.

NO need to create any method in Main2Activity and call it from MyFragment.
Best practice is , use startActivityForResult and onActivityResult.
Here is the code:

Fragment:

```
    public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
  }
  }
```

Main2Activity:

```
  public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

 private String myString = "hello";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
...

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", selectedPath1);
            returnIntent.putExtra("result2", selectedPath2);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();

}  
}
```

Simple.