# Passing in extra arguments for a viewable class?

Tags: java, android, xml, constructor

I am trying to define a class like so, so I can have it show up in XML:

```
public class MyLineChart extends com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyLineChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public MyLineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public LineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
    }

    // ...
}
```

So when I am defining this object I am doing:

```
mChart = (MyLineChart) findViewById(R.id.line_chart);
```

But what if I'd like to send in other arguments through the constructors? For example say the `MyLineChart` class had another field:

`private int mSomeInt;`

and I'd like to be able to set `mSomeInt` through the constructor so I am not just setting `mContext` to `context` but also `mSomeInt` to some integer I pass in. I'm using the integer as an example but it could technically be any argument.

Can this be done?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071725/pass-data-from-activity-to-fragment-class-cast-exception/37072002#37072002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when I am defining this object I am doing:

```
mChart = (MyLineChart) findViewById(R.id.line_chart);
```

Here, although you are assigning the `mChart` variable, you're not creating a `MyLineChart` object, you're just assigning an already created object to `mChart`.

If defined in some xml file (like I think you have done), then your class will be created by Android, using the following constructor:

```
public MyLineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
...
}
```

You could pass in attributes from xml, where you would parse `attrs` to extract their values. See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) on how to use custom attributes with your view if you're trying to pass in constant values, such as a colour for the view, or some default value.

If instead, you want to set some value that you only know at runtime, you can either:

1. Use a setter

   **I recommend this approach.** Just add a method to `MyLineChart` like

   ```
   void setMyValue(int myValue) {
     mMyValue = myValue;
     //notify parts of the view that this property has changed
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Create the object programatically.

   Here you don't include the view in xml, and instead create it programatically be replacing

   ```
   mChart = (MyLineChart) findViewById(R.id.line_chart);
   ```

   with

   ```
   mChart = new MyLineChart(context, myValue);
   //code that adds the view to the layout like a LinearLayout etc.
   ...
   ```

   For this to work you would create a new constructor for `MyLineChart`, something like

   ```
   public MyLineChart(Context context, int myValue) {
     super(context);
     mContext = context;
     mMyValue = myValue;
   }
   ```