# Android - How to create the instance of an Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

Although we can achieve to create a new instance of Fragment, why we can't do the same process to Activity class?

Who knows how we can manage activity from this perspective?

Comment: you don't create instance of activity (you don't new activity) you start an activity, OS and APIs take care of this for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class

Answer (score 2):

Activity instances are always created by the Android system. This is because a lot of initializations have to be done for the activity to work.

To create a new activity you call `startActivity` with an `Intent` describing the activity to start.

Comment: To add more to this answer. Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver and ContentProvider all are system components. Android OS is responsible for creating, managing and destroying the instance of them.

Answer (score 0):

Activity A should have a variable

`static ActivityA activityA;`

In onCreate state:

`activityA = this;`

---

and add this method:

`public static ActivityA getInstance(){
   return   activityA;
 }`

---

In activity B, call

---

`ActivityA.getInstance().myFunction();`

---

In order to get more information please go through this documentation:

[Android Activity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/index.html)

Comment: Actually, don't do that. There are just too many scenarios where this will go wrong. And probably even more serious the activity will then be never garbage collected.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: This does not seem right. It could become a source of memory leak.