# Instance of an activity class is null

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to create an instance of an activity in order to access methods in that class but whenever i call functions in that activity class I get this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void.
Here is my code

```
     public class SmsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
    
        private static SmsListActivity inst;
          public static SmsListActivity instance() {
    
            return inst;
        }
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }
        }
 SmsListActivity inst =  SmsListActivity.instance();
```

Comment: `I am trying to create an instance of an activity` you should never ever be doing this, there's no scenario where you would ever need to create an instance of an activity like this

Comment: The activity contains an array adapter list which I need to update from an smsreceiver class. The funny thing is it used to until today.

Comment: Do you have an alternative on how I can update the list.

Comment: there are lots of proper ways of handling this. use one activity with fragments or move out the data so that the list itself is static, at least then you'll be able to update it, but you're looking for trouble by doing this

Comment: What monstruosity is this

Comment: I am learning. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092371/android-how-to-create-the-instance-of-an-activity-class/48092519#:~:text=Activity%20instances%20are%20always%20created,describing%20the%20activity%20to%20start.

Comment: I see, if it's inside a Fragment, just call getActivity and check that is not null

Comment: You should add SMSReceiver class as well in the question.