# How to update text from recyclerview adapter to other layout xml

Tags: java, android

I have `ActivityCheckout.java` an adapter `AdapterServiceCourier` inside activity. The adapter class is for showing radio-button
price. How can I update `textview` with the view that is in ActivityCheckout.
like

```
public TextView getTextViewPriceOngkir()
{

    TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.price_ongkir);
    return txtView;
}
```

when I used in adapter `AdapterServiceCourier`:

```
ActivityCheckout ac = new ActivityCheckout();
            TextView tv = ac.getTextViewPriceOngkir();
            tv.setText("8");
```

its error like:

```
E/UncaughtException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

AdapterServiceCourier.java :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.APP_PUPUKKUJANG_MART, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String whois = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConfig.USER_WHOIS,null);
    row_index = -1;
    holder.itemView.setTag(service.get(position));
    final ServiceCourier p = service.get(position);
    holder.service.setText(p.getService());
    holder.desc.setText(p.getDescription());
    holder.cost.setText(p.getCost());
    holder.etd.setText(p.getEtd());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    View.OnClickListener rbClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) v;
            if(lastCheckedRB != null){
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.APP_PUPUKKUJANG_MART, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("ongkir_service", p.getService());
            editor.putString("ongkir_description", p.getDescription());
            editor.putString("ongkir_cost", p.getCost());
            editor.putString("ongkir_etd", p.getEtd());
            editor.apply();

            ActivityCheckout ac = new ActivityCheckout();
            TextView tv = ac.getTextViewPriceOngkir();
            tv.setText("8");
        }
    };
    holder.radiobutton.setOnClickListener(rbClick);
}
```

Display:
image click radio button, price must set to ongkir price
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqs2X.jpg)

Comment: attach your xml file.

Comment: Error is not in the code, error is mostly in xml file

Comment: [You cannot just create objects of Activities by using:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class)`ActivityCheckout ac = new ActivityCheckout();`

Comment: You are setting text into TextView  class which is not attached in your xml layout.

Comment: You can not new activity like this, the OS will create each activity. you should pass a reference of your activity to your adapter and put text in that textview

Comment: specify that when u want to update textView i mean when radio button selected

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki i update the question

Comment: @this where u initialized the adapter i mean in Activity checkout ?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki yes i initialize the adapter in avtivity checkout

Comment: @willy and textView which u want to update is in this activity

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Yes, of course

Comment: ok i will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Adapter Class OnClick RadioButton

```
View.OnClickListener rbClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) v;
        if(lastCheckedRB != null){
            lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
        }
        .....
        .....
        //Create Statis Mathod in ActivityCheckout and Access Hear
         ActivityCheckout.updateTextView(String DataUWantToAdd);
    }
};
```

And In Yout ActivityCheckout Class

**add static Mathod Dont miss That**

```
class ActivityCheckout
{
 .....
  //on create and etc
  public static void updateTextView(String DataUWantToUpadate)
  {
    yourTextViewObject.setText(DataUWantToUpdate);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is observable design pattern :

1. your activity should implements Observer interface
2. your adapter should extend Observable class
3. you should add your activity to your adapter
4. with `notiftyObserver` method you can update your activity

please note with [this design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) you can notify multiple activity.

Answer (score 0):

YourAdapter instance = new YourAdapter(context,arrayList,textView);

Now in constructor of adapter you can get access to that textview.

> YourAdpater.java

```
TextView textView;
YourAdapter(Context context,Arraylist<ModelClass> arraylist,TextView textView)
{
this.textView = textView;
}
```

Now in adapter you can update textview values.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Activity's method into adapter using context.Make one method with string parameter in activity which set string to your textview and call that method in your adapter when you want to change the text.