# Java : error: non-static method runCode(String,String) cannot be referenced from a static context MainActivity.runCode(userNum,msg);

Tags: java, android

i want runCode method to work if(mobNo.contains("16505556789")) is true, Please help java newbie Here

i have tried calling with obj but i couldnt make it work, please guide me a way by which a newbi can understand how to get this working
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myvisa;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.VoiceInteractor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.myvisa.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String phoneNum = "";
    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.saveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                phoneNum = binding.editTextText.getText().toString();
                saveData(phoneNum);
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveData(String phoneNumber){
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText("Your Number is "+phoneNumber);
    }

    public void runCode(String phnNuma, String msgSmsa){
        String url ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwU4ua3mEJzBl707fU7xA8b6MrxtRZGQ45zIjlvhGo0nsgtRXyCspxnwIJV0TP4yFjh/exec?";
        url = url + "action=create&userID="+phnNuma+"&smsOTP="+msgSmsa;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error.getMessage()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        Log.d("MsgDetails",phnNuma+msgSmsa);
    }
}
```

SmsReceiver.java

```
package com.example.myvisa;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String mobNo = "";
        String msg = "";
        String userNum = "";

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object[] smsObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        for(Object obj : smsObj){
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) obj);

            mobNo = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
            msg = message.getDisplayMessageBody();

            Log.d("MsgDetails", "MobNo:" + mobNo +", MSG - " + msg);
        }

        if (mobNo.contains("16505556789")){
            Log.d("MsgDetails","Number Matched");
            Log.d("MsgDetails", "userNum:" + userNum +", MSG - " + msg);
            MainActivity.runCode(userNum,msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Build Gradle .kts

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myvisa"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myvisa"
        minSdk = 31
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding=true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}
```

AnderoidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyVisa"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="15"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="01712-345678"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:text="Please Enter Active Phone Number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.158" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's actually happening in your code:

When you call `MainActivity.runCode(userNum,msg);`, the app assumes you're trying to call a static method named runCode. A static method can be called without creating an object of the class it's defined in. But runCode is not a static method. And that's why you're facing this problem.

To solve this you have to create an object of MainActivity. But you cannot simply create it using the new keyword like this: <s>`MainActivity activity = new MainActivity()`</s>

To learn how to get a reference to the MainActivity object, you can follow this thread: [Can I create an object of an Activity in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14956018/8192914)

But this is not a good solution for your case. The best practice would be to call the API using a service and start the service from the broadcast receiver.

So, your broadcast receiver would look something like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String mobNo = "";
        String msg = "";
        String userNum = "";
   ...............................
   ...............................
   ...............................
        if (mobNo.contains("16505556789")){
            Log.d("MsgDetails","Number Matched");
            Log.d("MsgDetails", "userNum:" + userNum +", MSG - " + msg);
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyApiService.class);
            // pass the phone number and message through the intent if necessary
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

The service class would look something like this:

```java
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Call the API here
    // get phone number and message from intent
    runCode(phoneNumber, message);
    return START_STICKY; // Adjust restart behavior as needed
}

private void runCode(String phnNuma, String msgSmsa){
        String url ="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwU4ua3mEJzBl707fU7xA8b6MrxtRZGQ45zIjlvhGo0nsgtRXyCspxnwIJV0TP4yFjh/exec?";
        url = url + "action=create&userID="+phnNuma+"&smsOTP="+msgSmsa;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error.getMessage()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        Log.d("MsgDetails",phnNuma+msgSmsa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method on the running instance of `MainActivity`:

```
if (context instanceof MainActivity activity) {
    activity.runCode(userNum, msg);
}
```